# Using Map remove the author name duplicate react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I loop through array of objects
Each object contents book title and author name.

I loop through the object to get authors names. without duplicate.
beacue there is for exmaple 5 books for same author

```
    <div className="container ">
    <div className="row ">
      
     {books.map(book(
      <div key={book.id}>
        <ul >
          <li >
            {book.author}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide examples of the data, and expected output.

Comment: You may want to adjust your data structure to something like `[ { authorName: '', bookTitles: [] }`. Loop over both the array of object and, for each author, loop over their titles.

Comment: You cannot use .map() to remove elements from an array. You also should already have the correct data when you're building JSX, so remove the dupes beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I use Filter to remove the duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only display author, you can do like this

books.map(b=>b.author) -> this one extracts only author names
new Set -> this remove duplicate author names

updated:

```
{[...new Set(books.map(b=>b.author))].map((author => <div key={author}>
        <ul >
          <li >
            {author}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     ))}
```

In case you want to display other properties other than author

```
[{id:1, author:"tom", anotherImage:"image 1"},{id:2, author:"tom", anotherImage:"image 1"}].filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.author===v.author))===i).map((book => <div key={book.id}>
    <ul >
      <li >
        {book.author}
        <img src={book.anotherImage}>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: "_do it like this"_ with a code-dump rarely makes a useful answer. You should add an explanation of what you've done (with links to relevant online documentation) to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will keep in mind when giving answers

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.
I updated the question could you help because i'm not sure how can I use your answer

Comment: I updated the answer, because the author is unique, you can use it as key

Comment: It is work Thank you but I need to use another vuale " authorImage" in same Map how can I use this vaule can I use like this b.anotherImage ?

Comment: If books have same author, do they have same anotherImage?

Comment: I mean author Image . each author has uniq image

Comment: I updated the answer which handles your needs

Answer (score 2):

If you take your data of objects and process them before you `map` over them you'll find the task easier.

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the data to create objects. In each the key is the author name, and the value is an object containing the author name, and an array containing their book titles.

Once the iteration is complete just return an array of object values using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which you can `map` over.

```css
.author { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

  function Example({ data }) {

    function processData(data) {
      return Object.values(data.reduce((acc, c) => {

        // Destructure the author and title from the
        // current object
        const { author, title } = c;

        // If the accumulator doesn't have a key
        // that matches the author assign a default
        // object to it, and then push in the title
        acc[author] ??= { author, titles: [] };
        acc[author].titles.push(title);

        // Return the accumulator for the
        // next iteration
        return acc;
      }, {}));
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{processData(data).map(obj => {
          const { author, titles } = obj;
          return (
            <section className="author">
              {author}
              <ul>{titles.map(title => <li>{title}</li>)}</ul>
            </section>
          );
        })}</p>
      </div>
    );

  }

  const data=[{author:"bob",title:"book1"},{author:"dave",title:"book2"},{author:"nicole",title:"book3"},{author:"nicole",title:"book4"},{author:"bob",title:"book5"},{author:"dave",title:"book6"}];

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('react')
  );

</script>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get exactly what you want, but I think that you want to select all the authors names without repeating.

One option it's to use the method reduce:

```js
  const authors = [{author:"Orwell"}, {author:"Knuth"}, {author:"JJ"}, {author: "JJ"}, {author:"Cormen"}, {author:"Knuth"}]
  const unduplicatedIterator = authors.reduce((set, obj) => set.add(obj.author), new Set()).keys()
```